# How to check if a SNS Topic is empty in a Step function code

Tags: amazon-sns, aws-step-functions

I am trying to check if a SNS that is populated from a lambda is empty in a AWS Step functions code, but from many resources the solution is to create another lambda that returns the suscription list.
In that way, is less efficient because there is more code to implement.

Is there any way to check this from a Step function?

I expect to check if the SNS is fully empty from the Step Function code.

Comment: What do you mean by, is SNS empty? It has no subscribers, or you mean empty message?

Comment: I have two subscribers, as triggers in two lambdas. So the idea is to check if the SNS is fully empty.

Comment: Unlike SQS queues, SNS topics are typically not thought of as having message state (retries and replays aside).  That's why @Caldazar asks what makes a topic "empty" or "non-empty" for you.